# get related values for int

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
    {"id": 1, "user_id": 999, "phone_number": "61412308310", "email": "can@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2, "user_id": 129, "phone_number": "61477708777", "email": "acdc@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 3, "user_id": 213, "phone_number": "61488908495", "email": "adel99@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 4, "user_id": 145, "phone_number": "61477708777", "email": "austr@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 5, "user_id": 214, "phone_number": "61421445777", "email": "austr@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 6, "user_id": 214, "phone_number": "61421445326", "email": "jango@gmail.com"},
])
```

There is a function that finds related rows. This function works if the value is of type list. How can I make it work with int(or float)?
For example, I want to find all related rows based on the value of the user_id column = 129. Since this is an int, the function will not work because of the line dataframe[dataframe.isin([value]).any(axis=1)]. If I try to find related rows based on the value of the phone_number column = ['61477708777'], the function will work correctly.

Function:

```
def get_related_values(data: pd.DataFrame, value: Union[int, list]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        
    related_values = data[data.isin(value).any(axis=1)]
    
    if set(np.array(value)) != set(np.array(related_values).reshape(-1)):
        return get_related_values(data, np.array(related_values).reshape(-1)) 
    else:
        return related_values
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the searched value in a list:

```
def get_related_values(data, value):
    related_values = data[data.isin(value).any(axis=1)]
    
    if set(np.array(value)) != set(np.array(related_values).reshape(-1)):
        return get_related_values(data, np.array(related_values).reshape(-1)) 
    else:
        return related_values
    
get_related_values(data, [214])
```

*NB. I also fixed the recursive function by replacing `find_related_values` with `get_related_values`.*

Output:

```
   id  user_id phone_number            email
1   2      129  61477708777   acdc@gmail.com
3   4      145  61477708777  austr@gmail.com
4   5      214  61421445777  austr@gmail.com
5   6      214  61421445326  jango@gmail.com
```